# How to understand newton (unit of force)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Simple question here for all of you, but I just wanted to form a mental image of the concept. I know the definition, but it's not 100% intuitive to me.

So, I imagine 1 newton as force that I apply on an object of 1 kg when I, say, smash it in some direction. It immediately receives acceleration of $1\:m\cdot s^{-2}$. Then, this object gains speed of $1\: \frac{m}{s}$ in 1 second and $\int_{0}^{n}1\:dt=n$ in $n$ second, until it stops for some reason like friction.

Thus, the graph of acceleration is straight line $a=1$ (right?) and the graph of speed is a line with slope 1, starting from (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you are correct with most. But you forget the mass, $kg$. It matters what the mass of the object is. The force required to hit a car to move it with that acceleration is much larger that if it was for something lighter.

Also, remember that force can be applied without any motion. You don't require acceleration to have force.

For me, **"1 Newton" is just the weight of an apple**. Simple and intuitive.

Comment: Ah, actually I specified it. Maybe you didn't notice :). Thanks for you answer.